# how are Updates and Deletes handled in both Data Warehouses and Data Lakes?

Tags: database, databricks, crud, warehouse, data-lakehouse

I'm trying to understand how Update and Delete functions are performed in Data Warehouses, Lakes and Lakehouses.

Databricks argues that they can perform upserts easily, which I would understand as adding CRUD capabilities.

I've read elsewhere that data lakes only get `CR`, and warehouses `CRU`.

Is this correct? how are Updates and Deletes handled in both Data Warehouses and Data Lakes?